# Error NDK Android Javac: error: Class names, are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested

Tags: java, android, opencv, jni

Estoy aprendiendo OpenCV para Android, y acorde a un tutorial que estaba viendo, tenía que configurar JNI.
Ya configuré Java y Ndk a fín de que sus comandos sean accesibles desde la linea de comandos, desde cualquier parte de la computadora. (Windows)

Tengo que ejecutar este comando en la terminal de android studio:

```
javah -d jni -classpath ../../build/intermediates/classes/debug bruno.volcovinsky.aprendiendoopencv.NativeClass
```

Se que javah ya no sirve, por lo que en su lugar uso javac, que me da el error mencionado en el titulo de la preguna. También intenté usando `javac -h` (que leí en algunos sitios)

El video donde ví que hay que hacer este paso es el siguiente: (Se abre automaticamente en el momento exacto) https://youtu.be/mF9fYdXfSD8?t=4m28s

Alguien sabe que puede ser lo que esté haciendo mal?

Comment: Por curiosidad: ¿por qué redactaste la pregunta en inglés? ¿Llegaste desde [so] o accediste directamente a [es.so]? Nos encontramos con este caso diariamente y nos sería muy útil saber el motivo de la confusión, para poder mostrar la información de manera más clara y explicitar que este es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas en castellano.

Comment: Supuse que el sitio estaba en español pero que  las preguntas aparecen tanto en la seccion en español como la version en ingles. Por eso la escribí en ingles para abarcar la mayor cantidad de gente posible.

Gracias, perdon la confusión!